# All email attachment files are corrupt in the python MIMEMultipart email

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I am trying to implement a mailer in python, which will run as a lambda function, but all my files that are getting delivered in the mail are corrupt and are not opening, except for txt files.

```py
mail = MIMEMultipart()
# mail = EmailMessage()
mail['To'] = data['to']
mail['From'] = sender
mail['Subject'] = populate_data_to_string(data['subject_data'], subject)

body = MIMEText(populate_data_to_string(data['data'], template), 'html')
mail.attach(body)

mail = load_attachments(mail, files)
mail = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mail.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

I am loading attachments as follows, Mind that file here is a `FieldStorage` object

```py
def load_attachments(mail, files):
    for file in files: # file is a FieldStorage
        content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file.filename)

        if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
            content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
        main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
        if main_type == 'text':
            attachment = MIMEText('r', _subtype=sub_type)
        elif main_type == 'image':
            attachment = MIMEImage('r', _subtype=sub_type)
        elif main_type == 'audio':
            attachment = MIMEAudio('r', _subtype=sub_type)
        else:
            attachment = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)

        attachment.set_payload(file.value)
        filename = file.filename
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)

        mail.attach(attachment)

    return mail
```

This mail is being sent using Gmail APIs

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I am actually reading the file in a AWS Lambda in form of a multipart form-data request. The file seems to be getting corrupted there.`, I couldn't notice it from your question. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize for my poor skill.